# Замена значений в списке

Tags: python

Как мне заменить два одинаковых значения из списка которые повторяются и стоят близко друг к другу `к примеру  nan, 5.75, 5.75, nan`  на nan и само значение `к примеру  nan, nan, 5.75, nan` ?

Пример, было:
 `l = [nan, 5.87, 5.87, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 5.87, nan, 5.87, nan, 5.87, nan, nan, nan, 5.81, 5.81, nan, nan, nan, nan, 5.95, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 5.89, nan, nan, 5.75, 5.75, nan, nan]`

Стало:
 `l = [nan, nan, 5.87, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 5.87, nan, 5.87, nan, 5.87, nan, nan, nan, nan, 5.81, nan, nan, nan, nan, 5.95, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 5.89, nan, nan, nan, 5.75, nan, nan]`

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно так:

```
l = ['nan', 5.87, 5.87, 'nan', 'nan', 'nan', 5.81, 5.81, 'nan']

n = [id > 0 and l[id] == l[id - 1] and 'nan' or l[id] for id in range(len(l))]
# result: ['nan', 5.87, 'nan', 'nan', 'nan', 'nan', 5.81, 'nan', 'nan']
```

Или так если надо первый заменять:

```
n = [id < len(l)-1 and l[id] == l[id + 1] and 'nan' or l[id] for id in range(len(l))]
# result: ['nan', 'nan', 5.87, 'nan', 'nan', 'nan', 'nan', 5.81, 'nan']
```

Comment: @CrazyElf Ничего не проверяется, как выглядит тернарный оператор в python  узнал только из поста ниже)) а суть этого выражения в том, что если условие выполняется до ' and nan' , то 'and non' вернёт nan , если нет, то or l[id] вернёт l[id]

Comment: А, пардон, спросонья не разглядел, что там без if )

Answer (score 3):

```
l = [None, 5.87, 5.87, 5.87, None, None, None, None, 5.87, None, 5.87, None, 5.87, None, None, None, 5.81, 5.81, None, None, None, None, 5.95, None, None, None, None, None, 5.89, None, None, 5.75, 5.75, None, None]

r = [l[i] if i == 0 or l[i] != l[i - 1] else None for i in range(len(l))]

print(l)
print(r)
```

логика простая - если текущий элемент не равен предыдущему или текущий элемент первый в списке - выводим его иначе `None`

`None` просто так написал, можно тот же `'nan'` использовать

Comment: l[i] if i == 0 or l[i] != l[i - 1] else None  --- где посмотреть правила такого cинтаксиса?  непоследовательно выглядит, хотелось бы разобраться)

Comment: обычный тернарный оператор в питоне который выглядит так `<действие для когда условие выполняется>if <действие> else <действие для которого условие не выполняется>`